# Why am I getting System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] instead of the list's contents?

Tags: c#, list, visual-studio

I decided to make a small little console based RPG to learn classes. I have a basic game going, but I have a problem. I'm trying to display the players inventory from the Player class in another class.

I'm using a List to hold the players inventory.

```
public List<string> inventory = new List<string>();
```

This is in the Players class file.

Then in the Shop Class, I'm doing;

```
Player player = new Player();
```

To make a new object to access the player class. Then to add something to the List in the shop, I'm doing;

```
player.inventory.Add("Axe");
```

But if I make the `player.inventory();` print out in the console, I get the wrong result:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]
```

How can I fix this? I should get `Axe` instead.

Answer (score 12):

It's not an error, it's just printing out the list. The default `ToString()` implementation of List simply prints the name of the type.

I'm guessing you want it to work like in PHP, where you print arrays separated by commas? Try:

```
string.Join(", ", player.inventory);
```

Answer (score 7):

You're trying to print a list object and not the values contained within the list, you need something like: -

```
foreach(var i in player.Inventory)
{
     Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Edit* As per comments

```
Console.Write(string.Join(System.Environment.NewLine, player.Inventory));
```

Comment: I used the example you posted. It works now and I'll use this until I work out how to put this into a one line piece of code.

Comment: @Jon, Why does it need to be a one liner? In many cases i'd choose the code that's more readable and easiest to maintain. However, i will edit my answer to include a one line solution so that you can see how it's done :)

Comment: Now that you've posted the one liner, the foreach loop is easier to understand.

Answer (score 4):

You require a `foreach` loop to iterate each and every member of your list.  You can't just print the list as a whole.

You need something like:

```
foreach(var i in Player.Inventory)
{
    Console.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

print next string to console, if you want to print all items at once:

```
string items = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, player.inventory);

Console.WriteLine(items);
```

this will print each item in separate line

By default `ToString()` (which is called on list when you pass it to `Console.WriteLine`) will print the **type** of the list, not the contents itself. That's why you receive *System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String].* on console screen.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to input all the inventory items, the flowing code should work:

```
foreach (string inventoryItem in player.inventory)
{
     Console.WriteLine(inventoryItem);
}
```

the player.inventory is a collection object and cannot be input directly.